# Convert Access desktop application to Web (SharePoint) based Access database

Tags: vba, ms-access

We have an SQL Express database with an Access 2003 front end which we can convert to Access 2010 or 2013. The database has a lot of forms, queries & tables & complex VBA code.

What is the procedure to make this web enabled so a limited number of our customers can logon and update information in the forms

Will it require VBA coding from scratch, some minor changes or I don't need to change the VBA code at all?

> Please note that I am talking about access web based database which
>   can be hosted on SharePoint site. I am not talking about php, java or
>   .net bases full fledge web application.  So i think a person having
>   expertise in MS Access can answer this question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're effectively starting over from scratch. It's months and months of development for a consulting company. Someone is going to need to write all of the web code for all of your forms. With the exception of your SQL, there's no reusing your existing code unless you want to go with Classic ASP, and that is a horrible idea.

Comment: Hi, please check my updated question. I am talking about access web based database actually.

Comment: Same answer. There's no magical "convert to web" tool. You're looking at some serious development time here.

Comment: Access web based database also uses VBA aa language right?

Comment: The former uses VBA, the latter in your case most likely asp.net in modern MSFT coding

Comment: No, classic ASP (which used VBA) has been completely phased out. I did most of my coding in it between '98 and '05, but for the last decade, everything uses .Net....

Comment: I think he is talking about [Access Web Apps](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-Access-app-25f3ab3e-510d-44b0-accf-b976c0813e71)

Comment: @Nick yes exactly. Any idea about Access Web Apps ?

Comment: You can build web forms in say Access 2010 and then publish them to the web. However, existing forms cannot be converted or re-used. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI    I should point out that you don't use HTML, asp.net or anything else. You 100% build the forms in Access and use the macro language as opposed to VBA. So no VBA is available in Access web.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Thanks for the answer. So if I got you correctly, VBA doesn't work in Access Web Apps and only the Data Macros work. And there is no way to convert an existing client side Access database to a Access Web App?